# Content Type is provisioning in SharePoint Online

Tags: pnp-powershell, pnp-provision, office-dev-pnp

I am aware that custom content type will not be available immediately in any existing site when we create a new one. In my experience, I have seen that it takes somewhere around 6-8 hours to appear in my site.

In my scenario, when I created the first site I waited for 6-8 hours and then created the list and then associate content type.

When I created my second site, I had to wait for another 6-8 hours in order to see the same content type.

So my question is, do I have to wait for 6-8 hours everytime I create a new site?

I am aware of PnP Provisioning and would like to know how PnP provisioning is handling this scenario.

In my business scenario sites are being created frequently. With on-perm we don't have to wait and sites is being created very quickly. With SPO this will be very much annoying for end user where user will have to wait for hours to see the sites.

Answer (score 2):

Using the content type hub will ensure that the site columns and content types will be available on every site collection and makes updates across the tenant pretty easy. The downside is that we'll have to wait for the timer job to kick in.
If you deploy the content types by hand or using some kind of framework then the content type will be available right away. However you will now have to deal with any later updates yourself.

Answer (score 1):

CTs are provisioned from the CTHub to the Site Collection which runs on a timer job. Yes, after a new SC is provisioned, you will have to wait for the timer job to complete a run.

Comment: Are you aware on how PnP Provisioning will handle this scenario?

Comment: No different than if you were performing it manually. It is all driven by a timer job which you have no control over.

Comment: Maybe I did not form my question properly. Let me elaborate. If I use PnP Provisioning to create a site and if the template has a content type which is not yet published, what will happen will the provisioning fail or it will keep checking for availability of content type?